# Reuse View JSF Primefaces

Tags: jsf, view, primefaces

i am developing an a JSF application using primefaces library , i would like to add "Back" and "Forward" buttons  so that the users can revisit previously visited pages ,i cannot use window.forward or window.backward since only the content in the page is changing (i have a ui:include which changes on the users request).So what i want to know is ,is there a feature where i could save the any jsf's attributes like viewId ,locale.renderKitId,contracts or anything else so that when a user clicks "back" i could restore that view with same values in display.Or is there any other way i could achieve this ? Please help

Thanks.

Comment: Look at primefaces Wizard.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ,but Wizard wont work in my case since i dont want to navigate between tabs ,My url is static,only the content is changing in the page by using "ui:include".